# Heading being duplicated

Tags: environments

I have a `thesis.tex` file that is set up as

```
\documentclass{report}
%packages
\usepackage{thesis_uvm}
%maketitle etc
\begin{document}
%abstract etc
%chapters
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

The `chicago.sty` and `.bst` as well as the example can be found [here](http://www.uvm.edu/~gss/uvm_thesis/).

The `thesis_uvm` style is

```
%% UVM Thesis Style
%% dvanhorn@cs.uvm.edu

\typeout{UVM Thesis Style, Version 0.1}
\typeout{Copyright (c) 2005 David Van Horn}
\typeout{Licensed under the Academic Free License version 2.0}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\else
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{framed}



\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.06in}


\newenvironment{references}[1]{
  % \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
  \singlespacing
  \section{References}
  \begin{list}
    {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{#1}
      \leftmargin\labelwidth
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{}
    \sloppy
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
  }{
  \end{list}
}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
  \newpage
  %\greenblock{Bibliography}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
  \singlespacing
  \section*{\refname\@mkboth
    {\uppercase{\refname}}{\uppercase{\refname}}}
  \begin{list}
    {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{#1}
      \leftmargin\labelwidth
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{}
    \sloppy
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
  }{
  \end{list}
  \newpage
}


% ===============================================
% don't split bibliography entries between pages
% ===============================================
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \clubpenalty10000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty10000}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  Is the posted sample really produced by the two files above?